# Angularjs form doesn't send value

Tags: angularjs

I have this form:

```
  <form>
          <select class="browser-default" ng-model="TAV">
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
          </select>

          <select class="browser-default" ng-model="COP">
            <option value="01">1</option>
            <option value="02">2</option>
            <option value="03">3</option>
            <option value="04">4</option>
            <option value="05">5</option>
          </select>
      <button class="btn-large modal-action waves-effect" ng-click="creaCOM('AMA')">AMARANTA</button>
      <button class="btn-large modal-action waves-effect" ng-click="creaCOM('FED')">FEDERICO</button>
  </form>
```

And this is my controller:

```
$scope.creaCOM = function(came) {
        var c = came;
        $http.post('/gest/include/inserisci_comanda.asp?came='+c+'&COP='+$scope.COP+'&TAV='+$scope.TAV)
            .success(function(){....})
            .error(function(){....})
};
```

Why doesn't the form send any value (except for c value called by ng-click!).
I want to use the button to send the form!

Comment: Did you try with `ng-option` ?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to use url params for a `post` request. Should be passing object as second argument of `$http.post()` instead

Comment: Post works on angular side, as can be seen from console : POST gest/include/inserisci_comanda.asp?came=AMA&COP=02&TAV=11 400 (Bad Request) So it should be something else

Comment: Can you check that a `<select>` `<option>` is marked as `selected` when the form submits?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your `creaCOM` function to the ng-submit attribute of the  `<form>` element, like:

```
<form
  ng-submit="creaCOM()">
...
</form>
```

Additionally, do not try to pass the form values by the function arguments. Use the defined ng-model variables. In your case, I would do:

```
  <form ng-submit="creaCOM()">
          <select class="browser-default" ng-model="TAV">
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
          </select>

          <select class="browser-default" ng-model="COP">
            <option value="01">1</option>
            <option value="02">2</option>
            <option value="03">3</option>
            <option value="04">4</option>
            <option value="05">5</option>
          </select>

            <select class="browser-default" ng-model="CAME">
                <option value="AMA">Amaranta</option>
                <option value="FED">Federico</option>
            </select>

      <button class="btn-large modal-action waves-effect" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

And in the controller (I did some changes, respecting that you invoke POST method):

```
$scope.creaCOM = function () {
        var postObj = {
                came: $scope.CAME,
                COP: $scope.COP,
                TAV: $scope.TAV
            };
        $http.post('/gest/include/inserisci_comanda.asp', postObj).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            ...
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            ...
          });
    };
```

It is just a code draft and a hint from my side.

Comment: Why the need of ng-submit? It's just an alternative.

Comment: Of course there is no need to use ng-submit, its only the popular convention. On the other hand, why to use <form> tag without intention to submit it? :)

Comment: You may read those both pages: https://books.google.fr/books?id=mZXjwz5X08EC&pg=PT313&lpg=PT313&dq=using+ng-submit+to+handle+form+submissions+mastering&source=bl&ots=T5B_TXV9T-&sig=gglBpNtPFkG-YdDWwbdPSJBfH_M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DzB0Veq8EMavU4KEgIAC&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=using%20ng-submit%20to%20handle%20form%20submissions%20mastering&f=false  It well explains the subtil difference between ng-submit and button.

Comment: @Mik378 - thank you for the link! I have never do the forms in Angular that way, I will remember this.

Comment: I think I explain me bad! I would send 3 value (TAV, COP, CAM), 2 with a select, and the last choicing a button (not with select!) Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. So:

```
  <button class="btn-large modal-action waves-effect" ng-click="creaCOM(reg.COP,'AMA')">AMARANTA</button>
  <button class="btn-large modal-action waves-effect" ng-click="creaCOM(reg.COP,'FED')">FEDERICO</button>
```

and then set this controller:

```
$scope.creaCOM = function(cop, cam) {....}
```

This works fine

Answer (score -1):

whether your scope value for TAV and COP is declared in controller?. Normall, POST method is called in form submit only and it posts all data to the url.